# Trying to compile hello world linux kernel module: missing MODULE_LICENSE()

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-kernel

I'm trying to compile the simplest kernel module possible, from the [The Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide](https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/Linux_Kernel_Module_Programming_Guide/x121.html). `hello.c`:

```c
#include <linux/module.h>   /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h>   /* Needed for KERN_INFO */

int init_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world 1.\n");

    /* 
     * A non 0 return means init_module failed; module can't be loaded. 
     */
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye world 1.\n");
}
```

`Makefile`:

```
obj-m = hello.o
KVERSION = $(shell uname -r)
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(KVERSION)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Output of `make`:

```
make -C /lib/modules/5.14.0/build M=/home/parallels/dev/demo modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/parallels/linux-5.14'
  CC [M]  /home/parallels/dev/demo/hello.o
  MODPOST /home/parallels/dev/demo/Module.symvers
ERROR: modpost: missing MODULE_LICENSE() in /home/parallels/dev/demo/hello.o
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modpost:150: /home/parallels/dev/demo/Module.symvers] Error 1
make[2]: *** Deleting file '/home/parallels/dev/demo/Module.symvers'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1766: modules] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/parallels/linux-5.14'
make: *** [Makefile:4: all] Error 2
```

This is all after I have compiled the linux kernel from source and run `make modules_install`. I don't really understand that second line of output: `make[1]: Entering directory '/home/parallels/linux-5.14'`, that is the directory in which I downloaded and compiled the linux kernel, I don't see what it has to do with this module I'm trying to compile.

I have seen others ask about this `missing MODULE_LICENSE()` error, but they are usually asking about much more complicated modules and the answers don't seem relevant to this very simple module. A few of the answers had to do with changing the name of either the source code file or the `.o` file, but trying either way simply produced errors about `no rule to make target` with the changed name.

Also, this is all on a vm of Kali linux running linux kernel 5.14.0 which I compiled from source.

Comment: Thanks for asking the question, it describe the question so well, nice job man

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add call to `MODULE_LICENSE` to your source file (`hello.c` in your case). This is what the error message is talking about. E.g.

```
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

---

Most modules also call `MODULE_AUTHOR`:

```
MODULE_AUTHOR("your-name");
```